# Replace one string of symbols including a carriage return

Tags: editors

This is borderline but  I do not how to do this in Texstudio.

I want to replace all the

```
\[
\begin{myenv}
```

by,

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{myenv}
```

Same with the closures,

```
\end{myenv}
\]
```

to

```
\end{myenv}
\end{equation*}
```

The thing is that there is a  carriage return put with the ENTER key of the keyboard.
I am on windows if it changes something.

Comment: This may not be a good option for you, but Emacs provides search and replace of characters like that via control-key sequences: `M-% \[^J\begin{myenv} RET \begin{equation*}^J\begin{myenv} RET`. The `^J` is a literally `Control-J` keystroke.  Perhaps something similar exists in TeXStudio.

Comment: `sed` or `gawk` spring to mind but not on Windows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me make a MWE file with two words and two carriage returns in Linux:

```
$ echo Hello > test.tex
$ echo Word  >> test.tex
```

What you see in `test.tex` in an text editor or with `$ cat test.tex` is:

> ```
> Hello
> Word
> ```

What you really have is....

```
$hd test.tex
```

> ```
> 00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 0a 57 6f  72 64 0a                 |Hello.Word.|
> 0000000b
> ```

...or ...

```
$ cat infile | od -c
```

> ```
> 0000000   H   e   l   l   o  \n   W   o   r   d  \n
> 0000013
> ```

...or ...

```
$cat -vte
```

> ```
> Hello$ 
> allWord$
> ```

Then, the hidden  symbol `$`or `0a` (hexadecimal) or `\n` (new line) that is the *carriage return* **and** *line feed* in Linux. Take into account that in files from Windows a new line could be coded as `^M` or `\r\n` where `\r` (0d) is the *carriage return* and `\n` the *line feed*.

So you need a tool able to find & replace strings including that hidden symbols. For simplicity, assuming that you have a Unix type file with only `\n`, you can do this with `sed`. For this sequence:

```
\[
\begin{myenv}
```

You can do:

```
$ sed 's/\[$/\begin\{equation\*\}/g' test.tex
```

> ```
> \begin{equation*}
> \begin{myenv}
> ```

(Append `> file.tex` i you want to save the result to `file.tex`)

Similarly, with the `vim` text editor you can do:

```
:%s/\\\[$/\\begin\{equation\*\}/
```

`Vim` as well as `sed` are in any Linux by default but there are also versions for Windows (not tested).

If you hate deal with escaped characters, this feature is also enabled in some text editors and word processors that have some option for regular expressions in the search tool. One common program in Linux and Windows that can do that is Libreoffice, so you can paste your code in this program, then `Ctrl-Alt-B` > Check `Other options` > Check `Regular expressions` box (Or something similar. Sorry, I'm just guessing from the Spanish version), then search and replace as showed in  the image,  and finally copy & paste the result in Texstudio.

**Edit**:None of the above is needed, as TeXstudio can do that (Wrongly, I assumed the contrary due to the question). You only need check the `Regexp` option after doing `Ctrl-R` and input the strings just as in the Libreoffice example. I left the another solutions for users with simpler editors.

[image: MWE]